# Is it possible to Repeat Icons in flutter like ImageRepeat

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, repeat

I am wondering if it is possible to repeat an actual icon widget like the image I have attached.

Currently getting this result using ImageRepeat but would like to be able to use and actual icon so it can be modular and the icon can change.

( the repeating image can currently change but I don't want to have to create 100 images of icons. )

Current Solution:

```
SizedBox.expand(
 child: Image.asset(
  _backGroundImage,
  repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
)),
```

[image: Desired Result using ImageRepeat.repeat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Wrap:

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Wrap(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(2000, (int index) {
            return Icon(Icons.add);
          }),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Didn't know about generate.

Comment: always the first time~